# How should you use bumpversion in databricks?

Tags: git, databricks, versioning

I've cloned my repo onto databricks and want to push my updates, and we use bumpversion to manage versions. Is there a good way to use bumpversion on databricks?

The lack of terminal is quite confusing - I've settled for now making a notebook and writing

```
! pip install bumpversion
! bumpversion minor
```

in a cell then deleting the file, which is pretty horrible and hacky. Is there no better way to manage repos?